# Hazelcast - I/O imbalance detected, but no suitable migration candidate was found

Tags: hazelcast

We are using distributed Hazelcast. We are seeing the following error message. 
[hz.defaulttenant-defaultorg0.IOBalancerThread - ] DEBUG c.h.n.tcp.iobalancer.IOBalancer - [10.50.40.86]:5706 [defaulttenant-defaultorg0] [3.5] There had been I/O imbalance detected, but no suitable migration candidate was found.

What is the meaning of this message?

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error message as the log level is `debug`. You can just ignore this message or better configure the logging to log info or higher only.